# Android Google Analytics V2 myTracker

Tags: android, google-analytics

I would like to track a view in my Android application using Manual Screen Tracking. I read here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/screens that I need to use this code:

```
myTracker.trackView("Home Screen");
```

But Eclipse shows an error (myTracker cannot be resolved) when I use it.

I have no trouble with EasyTracker.

```
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker;

EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this);
```

Comment: Can you post a little more of your code? Have you declared myTracker anywhere?

Comment: I'm new to this and I don't know how to declare myTracker.

Comment: You can see a few examples at the [Google Analytics Developer docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/advanced). I'm not sure which one is best for your use case, but one of them should be suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Tracker myTracker = EasyTracker.getTracker();
myTracker.trackView("Home Screen");
```

Comment: In beta 5 `trackView` is deprecated instead use `sendView`.